# From csv, How can I plot 2 variables (P vs V) in a plot with 3rd variable (tot_r) determining the shade of the coordinate? (In python)

Tags: python, csv, plot, pca

As in csv file below, How can I plot 2 variables (P vs V) in a plot with 3rd variable (tot_r) determining the shade of the coordinate? (In python).
Total dataset is of 100,000 rows.

[csv file- P,V,tot_r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAb7P.png)

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

From the data, looks like `p, V, tot_r` are all continuous. So, code below will pull the data from file `data.csv` and build a scatter plot as shown in attached graph

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
cmap = sns.cubehelix_palette(as_cmap=True)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))
points = ax.scatter(df.p, df.V, c=df.tot_r, s=30, cmap=cmap)
f.colorbar(points)
```

Graphs output

[image: Graph]